# Regular expression for a password

Tags: regex

A regular expression for password

- It should have  one number
- One character compulsorily
- Not case sensitive.
- Special character is not mandatory.

`xyz.match(/^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i)`

In this if we give special character it is not accepting

```
asd12   //working
Asd123  //working
Asd123@ //not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 look-aheads anchored at the beginning instead of a non-capturing group:

```
/^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]).*$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `.*` subpattern will allow any characters, but the look-aheads will demand at least 1 digit and 1 Latin letter.

Note that non-capturing groups still consume characters, and cannot be used to *check* for presence or absence of specific subpatterns in a string. Only [zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) provide that mechanism.

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW1nW1/2)

Comment: its working thank you :)

Comment: FYI: if you want to match `xyz1` and `123xyz`, but not match `123xyz@`, use `/^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*$/i` (the same `[a-z0-9]*` as in your original regex).

Comment: Could you please update the programming language tag? Is it JavaScript?

Comment: thank you its prototype. Accepted the answer :)